# Using XPATH, how do I select multiple elements while retaining the path

Tags: select, xpath, element

Assuming I have a XML like so:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <i>data</i>
    <ii>data</ii>
    <iii>data</iii>
  </b>
  <b>
    <i>data<i>
    <ii>data<ii>
    <iii>data</iii>
  </b>
</a>
```

Using XPath, how would I select the above XML to create a structure like so:

```
  <b>
    <i>data</i>
    <ii>data</ii>
  </b>
  <b>
    <i>data<i>
    <ii>data<ii>
  </b>
```

In this scenario I'm only interested in i and ii and, but want to retain the outer element.  I also cannot use XSLT, only XPATH statements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm wrong, but I thought XPATH only selects sequences of "nodes", in its own abstract model. I would be lost without XSLT here.

Comment: I believe your right Zedoo.  There is no way, so far, that I can select element "b" with child "i" and "ii".  You will always get the extra children nodes ("iii").  Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 3):

```
/a/*/i/..|/a/*/ii/..
```

"From a, select all children, then select all "i" elements, then select the parent, OR from a select all children then select all "ii" elements, then select the parent.

Answer (score 1):

To select all nodes  and  including their parent, outer nodes:

```
/a[i or ii]|/a/i|/a/ii|/b[i or ii]|/b/i|/b/ii
```